How to access CiviCRM API functions from a WordPress plugin
Wondering what I need to include/require in a WordPress plugin to access the CiviCRM API functions from within that plugin (assuming that CiviCRM is installed on this WordPress installation).
Or is the API just automatically available?

Well I guess I answered this myself...
You do not need to add any includes or requires.
The CiviCRM API is just availble automatically in a WordPress plugin.
